Vivado warning: extra semicolon in not allowed here in this dialect; use SystemVerilog mode instead
Testbench source code:

I have a testbench from another project which has the same structure, but I haven't seen this error:
module tb_Traffic_lighter_controller_HIGH;

reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [2:0] num;
reg [2:0] duty_cycle;
wire out,red,yellow,green;

Traffic_lighter_controller_HIGH Traffic_lighter_controller_HIGH_1(clk,reset,num,duty_cycle,out,red,yellow,green);

initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    num = 2;
    duty_cycle = 3; 
    #20 reset = 0;
end

always #10 clk = ~clk;
endmodule


initial beign ? :)

I’m voting to close this question because It was a typo, unlikely to help others

As noted in a comment from Vlad, in the test bench source code in the picture begin is misspelt as beign.
I haven't attempted to use the testbench code in Vivado, but it is likely that the misspelt beign at line 12 results in the syntax error reported on line 13.

Another hint is that beign is not colored: it has no syntax highlighting, like other keywords initial and end.
